# In app purchase give error offer token is null after upgrade package to in_app_purchase 3.1.7

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I have implemented non consumable in app purchase in my flutter app. after upgrade in app purchase package purchase dialog not shown and its give me below error:

PlatformException(INVALID_OFFER_TOKEN, Offer token null for product monthly is not valid. Make sure to only pass offer tokens that belong to the product. To obtain offer tokens for a product, fetch the products. An example of how to fetch the products could be found here: https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase/README.md#loading-products-for-sale, null, null)

I don't have any offer with my base plan.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. To resolve the issue related to the in-app purchase library in Flutter, you can use version 3.1.5 of the library.

In the latest version, 3.1.7 of the in-app purchase library, it internally relies on the in_app_purchase_android library with a version of ^0.3.0+8. In this version, the offer token is mandatory, which can cause issues with invalid offer tokens, whether or not you have added a token in the Play Store.

To avoid these issues, you can specifically use version 3.1.5 of the in_app_purchase library. This version should not have the mandatory offer token requirement and can help resolve the problem.

Make sure to update your `pubspec.yaml` file with the following line under the dependencies section:

```yaml
dependencies:
  in_app_purchase: 3.1.5
```

After saving the file, run `flutter pub get` to fetch the specified version of the library and resolve the issue.

By using version 3.1.5 of the in_app_purchase library, you should be able to avoid the problems related to the mandatory offer token requirement.

Comment: thankyou! I will try this solution and will provide an update!!

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using the product details returned from `queryProductDetails`. I had the same issue and that fixed it.

Here is an example, be sure to update it with the correct product id.

```
Future<void> purchaseSubscription() async {
  final productDetailsResponse = await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails({YOUR_PRODUCT_ID});
  final productDetails = productDetailsResponse.productDetails.firstOrNull;

  if (productDetails != null) {
    final purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails);
    await InAppPurchase.instance.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
  }
}
```

**Edit: Background on my issue**

I created my own model which copied the properties from the `ProductDetails` that was returned, so that I didn't need to call `queryProductDetails` again. The issue was that the model returned from `queryProductDetails` on Android is `GooglePlayProductDetails`. I wasn't checking the type if it was `GooglePlayProductDetails` and was only handling it as if it were `ProductDetails`. `GooglePlayProductDetails` has additional properties, and these were weren't being copied and were therefore lost. To make the purchase I was instantiating `ProductDetails` which would then be used to instantiate `PurchaseParam`, this meant that the additional fields were not present and hence why the purchase fails with this error.

The reason the solution above works is because it uses the `GooglePlayProductDetails` which has all the properties that are required.

In hindsight, my attempt to "optimize" wasn't so well thought through because in the future if more properties were added to `GooglePlayProductDetails` then I would have to add them to my own custom model which seems like something that would be very easy to miss. That's why I think it is a better solution.

Comment: Can you explain this? why did it work? and why it wasn't working without it.

Comment: I updated the answer because I ran out of characters to post as a comment! I hope that answers your questions :)

Comment: @guranga thanks so much for your comment. I also did exactly the same and abstracted everything behind an interface to avoid package dependencies. This is the first time this approach totally messed quite alot of things up. Will have to rethink how I abstract data away in general. Thanks again!

Comment: Your comment has made my day, thanks @ChristianX. I'm glad it helped :) 
Happy coding!